# Navigation possibilities with 5 different items

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education, factorial

How many possibilities does a navigation have with 5 different items.

I first though of 5x5 but that is not enough I think.

For example, these are some possibilities:

The letters represent simple navigation text items like Home, Users, Login ...

```
A

B

C

D

E

A     B     C     D     E

A     B     C     D

A     B     C 

A     B  

A   
...
```

if I have for example this:

```
A    B
```

and

```
B    A
```

it is redundant in my case, the order is not important.

Comment: I don't understand what a "navigation with n items" represents.

Comment: just buttons or text items like Home | Users | Tags ...., I shortened them with letters in my example

Comment: And the question is about combinations containing from 1 to 5 of those 5 items?

Comment: Your question is as clear as the skies over Beijing on a bad day.

Comment: @gunbl4d3 yes it is about the combination

Comment: By navigation, can I assume $A, B, C...$ to be independent unit vectors in different directions. And the no. of ways to find new vectors by finding sum of any or all of these vectors.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking how many non-empty subsets exist for a five element set.  As there are $2^n$ subsets for an $n$ element set including the empty subset, there are $2^5-1=31$ subsets here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of ways to select $m$ elements from a set of $N$ elements is given by the combinatorial number $N \choose m$.

So the number of combinations of 1 to 5 elements from a set of 5 elements is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^5 {5 \choose i}=31$$

Answer (score 0):

The number of different locations you can reach with $n$ navigation directions is

$$^nC_1+ ^nC_2+...+^nC_n=(1+1)^n-1=2^n-1$$